# How to store Cloudwatch agent config file as "securestring" on AWS Parameter Store?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-ssm, aws-parameter-store

We are storing the `Cloudwatch agent config file` on `AWS Parameter Store`.
We fetch the config (using `fetch-config` clause in `amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl`) from above parameter store while starting the Cloudwatch agent.

If the config file is stored as `encrypted`, the `fetch-config` fails. It succeeds if the config file is NOT encrypted.

```
sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -s -c ssm:<parameter-store-name>
```

How to successfully do a `fetch-config` on an encrypted config file stored on AWS Parameter Store while starting Cloudwatch agent?

Answer (score 1):

1. your ec2 instance needs proper permissions to KMS key,
2. Also KMS resource policy must grant you ec2 instance profile to decrypt,

Each of these permissions you can check by the following command:
`aws ssm get-parameters ... --with-decryption`

I'm not sure if its possible to fetch parameter using `-c ssm:`, instead you can try `get-parameters`, save parameter in the fail, and then use it with `-c file:`.

Here you can find more information about decrypting parameters: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/param-create-cli.html#param-create-cli-securestring